# How much property damage did Batman commit while evading the GCPD?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, batman-begins

In the movie Batman Begins, Batman is seen speeding the Batmobile across Gotham in order to evade the pursuing GCPD.

**What is the estimated cost of the damage done?**

Comment: Since Bruce Wayne owns half of Gotham, it's in Batman's best interests to avoid causing too much damage. It's a bit like keying his own car.

Comment: I wonder if insurance contracts in Gotham have "Acts of Batman" clauses in them.

Comment: @Valorum Is it established somewhere in Batman Begins that Bruce Wayne, Alfred, or the Wayne company owns half of Gotham?

Comment: @TylerH - I was being ironical. That said, this sounds like the foundation for a good question for Thaddeus to answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the sequence shown, the following property damage occurs.

> 5 x Police cars
>   3 x Plastic dustbins
>   1 x Glass store-frontage
>   1 x Car park barrier
>   2 x Compact cars (used)
>   1 x Concrete car park wall
>   1 x Air-conditioning unit (roof)
>   3 x Heat-exchanger chimneys
>   1 x Mesh wire fence
>   1 x Building wiring loop
>   1 x Rooftop satellite dish
>   1 x Tiled roof (commercial)
>   1 x Central reservation barrier
>   1 x Divider fence
>   1 x Construction warning sign
>   1 x Concrete motorway divider
>   1 x Roadside hut
>   1 x Metal fence

**Structural Damage:** The major damage caused in the sequence is the destruction of the tiled roof of what appears to be a commercial building. We would easily expect that to cost upwards of $100,000 to repair. He also blew up several walls and dividers that could cost $10-30,000 to fix.

**Cars:** Assuming the police cars are written off (but suffer no major damage to their internal systems or engines) there's a price-tag of around approx $20,000 *per car* (times 5). The two compact cars suffer some side-damage but are probably repairable at a cost of around $1500 per car.

**Misc damage:** Without knowing the relative cost of building materials in Gotham it's hard to say, but I'd imagine something around $20-30,000 would be sufficient to cover the replacement of these items.

### Best guess. $300K (ish).

Comment: Is that from Screen Junkies?

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - I just counted it and guesstimated.

Comment: I used a figure of $500 for all of the small misc items, $1000 for large misc items and the approx cost of completely replacing everything else.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile I thought CinemaSins did the damage count, not Screen Junkies.

Comment: Does that include the money that the city had to pay out to the injured officers in the police cars?

Comment: @BenMiller - I am assuming that they were all miraculously unharmed.

Comment: @Valorum Indeed; miraculously avoiding accidental casualties is Batman's *true* superpower. This becomes especially obvious when watching TAS, which carefully shows every single person who looks like they might have been fatally wounded (e.g. from falling) shaken but otherwise unharmed a moment later.

Comment: Only 300k? The Tumbler itself probably cost more than that to build.

Comment: @Ellesedil - It's pretty much unscathed by the end of the chase. I'd estimate the service costs and buffing out the scratches might add a couple of thousand dollars.

Comment: I'm only asking about property damage. Assume all officers were miraculously unharmed. Btw the roadside hut seems to be enclosed and wired so that likely cost more. And as far as building material costs, the Dark Knight Trilogy gotham is fictionally located in New Jersey, so state rates should do.

Comment: @Matthew - I've already padded my estimate by nearly $50k to give myself some wiggle room :-)